# struct inside struct and typecasting

Tags: c

Today I found this code which looks like an elongated piece without any need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
     //BLABLABLA
}
structA;

typedef struct
{
    //BLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
}
structB;

typedef struct
{
    structA A_obj;
    structB B_obj;
}
structC;


int main(void)
{
    structA *A_ptr;
    structC  C_obj;

    A_ptr = (structA *)(& (C_obj.A_obj)); //THIS LOOKS OVER-ENGINEERED
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand why it was done like this rather than just using `malloc()` to allocate space directly using `structA`'s size or using `structA`'s object to be pointed by `A_ptr`?

Comment: Can you share more details about the compiler used and compiler flags (was any specific packing requested)? Were there any unions used anywhere?

Comment: There is no enough here to know why this was done or whether it was necessarily. The individual line `A_ptr = (structA *)(& (C_obj.A_obj));` certainly could be just `A_ptr = &C_obj.A_obj;`. But as to why `structC` was built with two structures in it even though only a pointer to the first is used at first is unclear. If there is no other code using it, there is no point to this. If there is other code using this, there could be a reason. You would have to show the other code.

Comment: C extends A and B? It would be hard to tell without some context.

Answer (score -1):

There's a big difference between using `malloc()` and not doing so. For instance `A_ptr` if was returned from a function would be invalid in the scope where the function has already finished excuting, which means that the `A_ptr` is now pointing to "*invalid*" memory.

You also cannot `free()` that pointer. And as explained above it can only be used anywhere before the function where the actual object was allocated exits.

It was done like this to have a pointer to a local variable probably just inside a function, it's hard to say what the motivation was without seeing the actual use case.

Also note that the member of type `structA` is not a pointer so you can't assign to it a pointer. You can create a pointer to it like they did in `A_ptr = ...`.

Comment: `A_ptr` might have been popped by the time function was over but the address allocated to `A_ptr` by `malloc` would still be valid and if somewhere (from where the function has been called) memory address pointed by`A_ptr`' is returned then the `malloc'ed memory would still be accessible. Please correct me if I am wrong. PLUS this all is happening just within a function.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If this is happening all of it within a function then probably the pointer was used just to avoid the awkward syntax. Say if `A_ptr` is used multiple times within the function. I would do it!